# Webpack ignores port setting

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to run my React app via WebPack, but the tool seems to ignore my port setting. Instead, it uses the default `8080` port or a random port (this varies everytime I run the project). Here is an excerpt from my `webpack.development.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path')
const appJsPath = path.join(__dirname, './src')
const bundelJsPath = path.join(__dirname, './build')

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-cheap-module-source-map',
    context: appJsPath,
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
      myApp: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './main.js'
      ]
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(bundelJsPath, '[name].bundle.js'),
      port: 4040
    },
    // output: {
    //   path: bundelJsPath,
    //   filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    //   publicPath: 'http://localhost:4000/'
    // },
```

I have checked the ports `4000` and `4040`, and they are not used by any process (I am on a Windows 10 system). I have tried both settings, `devServer` and `output`, but neither of them work. Restarting the system did not help either. What am I doing wrong?

I am starting the app by running `yarn dev`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "yarn run clean && webpack-serve --config ./webpack.development.config.js && yarn run css",
    "clean": "rimraf ./build",
    "css": "uglifycss ./css/style.css > ./css/style.min.css"
}
```

Comment: How you are starting the dev server? can we see npm script?

Comment: I have added the relevant scripts.

Comment: why not webpack-dev-server?

Comment: I don't know, it is a legacy app that I am trying to update.